# Does it make sense to use a local API within an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

For example, I have an application that currently uses basic HTML, as well as IPC between the renderer and the main process of my application. Would it make sense to have let's say, a hidden window with an Express API running and another window with the content and requests being made to the API?

What's the correct way to build an Electron app securely, so with nodeIntegration set to false, etc. (not that I need to but I want to do things the right way) and still be able to communicate between the two processes? Is there any reason not to create an Express API to replace my current IPC solution?